# Visual Studio 2010: Specify working directory when running custom build tools on individual files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project that contains files that need to be processed using an in-house custom build tool that generates C++ code.

I have gone through the steps to add a custom build tool for each of these files.  In the Custom Build Tool command line, use "call" to ensure that the custom build tool runs for all these files before compiling C++ code.

The only problem is that the custom build tool needs to be run from the directory where the files live, not from the location of the Visual Studio solution.

I see a few possible options right now, and none of them is ideal:

1. Change the custom build tool command line on the first file to:  "cd workingdir && call custom-tool ..."  I dislike this because it is fragile – if I add a new file that is alphabetically before the first file, I have to remember that it needs this special step in the custom build step.
2. Create a batch file that changes the working directory, calls the custom build tool, and changes back.  Call this batch file from Visual Studio.
3. Use "start" instead of "call" to call the custom build tool.  This comes with the downside of opening up a command shell for each file (and it looks like these command shells need to be closed manually).

Is there a better option for running a custom build tool on a file from a working directory?

Thank you.

Comment: Since the tool was made in-house, could it be changed to take the full path to the file in question as an argument, cd to its working directory, and then do whatever it does there?

Comment: I'd go with the batch file I think.

Comment: Thanks!  We may change the build tool eventually, but sadly not quickly enough for my project.

Comment: When you looked at using `Start`, _I'm assuming with its `/D` option_, did you try including its `/B` and if necessary `/Wait` options? e.g. `Start ["Title"] [/D Path] [/Wait] [/B] [Command/Program] [Parameters]`.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio project files are MSBuild files. So you can modify project file manually and perform additional actions when building project in VS.

To do this:

1. Create a simple MSbuild file named e.g. `MyCustomtool.target`. This file "override" MSBuild target and call your custom tool.

Here is sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Calling custom tool for %(ClCompile.Identity)"/>
    <Exec Command="customtool.exe %(ClCompile.Identity)" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This file:
"override" target name "BeforeBuild" and for each file defined in the group "ClCompile" displays text message and execute customtool.exe with name compiled .cpp file as param.

2. You must modify your .vcxproj file and before last line containst `</Project>` import your file adding a line:

`<Import Project="MyCustomtool.target"/>`

After this Visual Studio will execute yours custom tool for every file in project.

Some comments:

- because I do not have installed VS 2010 I'm not 100% sure which target name you can use. I think that "BeforeBuild" should be valid for VS 2010 (in VS 2017 I'm using "BeforeBuildGenerateSources").
- You can change option "Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and run/MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "detailed", see detailed output from build process and check target names.
- File group "ClCompile" contains all *.cpp files. You can check file group names in your .vcxproj file.
- You can set working directory for your custom tool (as above). If you need in your MSBuild file you can use VisualStudio macros like $(ProjectDir), $(OutDir) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple caller application changing the working directory and calling your build tool as a child process. You use Visual Studio, so I suppose your platform is Windows. In this case the code for the application can be as simple as follows (it is in C, based on an example from MSDN)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s working_directory !cmdline\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!SetCurrentDirectory(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("SetCurrentDirectory failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    LPTSTR commandLine = GetCommandLine();
    while (*commandLine && *commandLine != '!')
        ++commandLine;
    ++commandLine;

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, commandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    DWORD exitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return exitCode;
}
```

It receives the new working directory as the first argument, than searches for ! in the command line and treats everything after it as the child process command line. This is very handy, because you don't need to bother with quoting quotation marks etc. E.g.

`cdandcall.exe C:\Windows !python -c "import os; print(os.path.abspath('.'))"`

Will print `C:\Windows` in the output. (Certainly if you compiled the application as `cdandcall.exe`, have `python` on your `PATH` and the folder `C:\Windows` exists).